# SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused

Tags: symfony, mariadb

Самое интересное, что миграции накатываются, т.е. с соединением все ок, а через браузер уже открыть не удается, пишет в доступе отказано (connection refused). в чем косяк?

использую mariaDB на докере, версия марии 10.5.5

`docker-compose.yml`

```
    mysql:
        image: 'mariadb'
        restart: always
        environment:
            - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=pass
            - MYSQL_DATABASE=dbname
            - MYSQL_USER=user
            - MYSQL_PASSWORD=pass
        volumes:
            - ./data/mysql:/var/lib/mysql
        ports:
            - 3306:3306
        networks:
            - task
```

`.env`

```
DATABASE_URL=mysql://user:pass@127.0.0.1:3306/dbname?serverVersion=mariadb-10.5.5
```

Comment: приложение в докере?

Comment: @SergeiKirjanov нет, только бд